# How to call a view function by method id from web3?

Tags: solidity, evm

To call a closed source contract that requires sending a tx, we can just simply set the "data" like this pattern: METHOD_ID + PARAM0 + PARAM1 + ... then sign and send.

My question is, how to do that with view functions with web3? (I know the method id by decompiling the bytecode and I will brute force the params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a view function from a contract using [`web3.eth.call`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth.html#call)

Example copied from the  web3 docs

```
web3.eth.call({
    to: "0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe", // contract address
    data: "0xc6888fa10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003"
})
.then(console.log);
```